# Did the Buddha tell how to visit another part of universe via meditation?

Tags: the-buddha, psychic-powers

Based on [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1503/9846) I came to know that the Buddha has spoken about life on other planets; so did he ever explain any method, how to visit those places while doing meditation?

Weirdly I have read this in Hinduism as well: that it's easy to visit another planet using your mind, instead of wasting more time and resources by physical means, but I never find a method to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha mentioned many supernatural powers called *siddhi* but he did not teach them. He mentions that samadhi is required to developing siddhi but since siddi do not help to end dukkha the Buddha doesn't explain exactly how to develop siddhi.

Comment: one of his monk show to people that he can fly and when buddha came to know he told him not to show it again , right ?

Answer (score 1):

As for what I have heard in Dhamma deshana, if a person keeps such an intention in mind while meditating that person won't be able to achieve that. You need to lower your expectations to achieve such peaceful levels in meditation. Or else those extreme desires will be hunting your mind without letting you meditate in the proper way.
So if you meditate with the pure intention of ending the sansara,  Such things will come to you automatically.